# How to create a memory breakpoint in lua

Tags: debugging, lua

I use ZeroBrane debugger for lua, and I have not found a way to set a memory breakpoint.
As a poor man's soulution I've implemented the code for table tracking mentioned in [PIL](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html).

The usage of the code is limited to t = track(t), where only access through t is tracked, not other references.

```
t = {}
t2= t

-- some code

t = track(t)

operate(t2) -- not tracking access/assignment
```

How would you go on to tracking the actual table, not just the reference, so the above example would boil down to:

```
t = {}
t2= t

-- some code

track(t)

operate(t2) -- tracking access/assignment
```

Comment: ["Both __index and __newindex are relevant only when the index does not exist in the table. The only way to catch all accesses to a table is to keep it empty. So, if we want to monitor all accesses to a table, we should create a proxy for the real table."](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html) are accurate statements.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Well, you could rewrite track to move all values in t to a backing table and make t the proxy table instead of the new table.

Comment: That seems like a cosmetic fix that might force proper use. Still the problem remains. If you don't catch the table at creation, you might have another reference messing with table data.

Comment: "actual table, not just the reference": There is no access to tables except through references. It doesn't matter when a reference is assigned to a variable. It accesses the table just like any other reference. ["By default, a value has no metatable, /except/ the string type."](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4). So, any time after the modified track gets a chance do its thing, all references to the same table will be affected. [C-like memory breakpoints and C++-like reference variables are foreign concepts.]

Comment: I understand that all references will be affected when the tracked table is affected. Tracking will not destroy program correctness. Thanks for your answers.